# How to turn down a job after you consulted for the same company?

Tags: professionalism, job-offer, consulting

I have been  consulting part-time for a company for a while (less than a year).  We have seriously talked about me joining the company - discussed role and compensation.  I have been interviewing at other places and now wish to accept a job elsewhere.

How do I break it to the company I am consulting for?

Answer (score 9):

> How do I break it to the company I am consulting for?

Nothing special here.

Just tell them that you enjoyed working with them, and have appreciated the possibility of joining the company, but have decided to accept a position elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Tell it to them just like that, that someone else had given you a better offer and you're looking to accept it.

The company you're consulting for right now might come up with a new offer for you once you tell them that, and then you can decide how to go from there. As long as you haven't signed a contract with anyone, then you're free to negotiate with every potential employer.